# How can I generate a XAML WPF document to be printed from a web service?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, service, printing

I have a XAML WPF control that I populate with data and then allow the users to print from our WPF application.

Now we need the ability to populate and print the same document from a (headless) web service.

I tried adding our WPF project as a reference in (weak) hopes that it might just work, but visual studio acts like it can't find the assembly (yellow warning icon on the reference, and it can't find the relevant namespaces when compiling), even though it takes me successfully to the object explorer for the assembly when I double click on it.

I would rather not just launch a GUI exe from a service.  I would prefer doing the processing headless if at all possible.

Has anyone done this?

Comment: `RenderTargetBitmap` may be an option, it will allow you to create `WPF` elements and save as a `BitmapImage` that you could then print, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I do this at the moment, here's my code. I also had to add some extra code to run it in a separate thread that used the STA Apartment State as some of the controls needed it, not sure if you'll need to do that too.

(This code was in VB.NET (don't ask) but I've used an online converter so it's in c# so it's formatted more nicer by stackoverflow.)

Don't change the Screen DPI as this is a windows default (also don't ask).

```
private byte[] Render(FrameworkElement element)
{
    const double SCREEN_DPI = 96.0;
    const double TARGET_DPI = 300.0;

    // Setup the bounds of the image
    Rect bounds = new Rect(0, 0, element.Width, element.Height);
    element.Measure(bounds.Size);
    element.Arrange(bounds);
    element.UpdateLayout();


    // Create the target bitmap
    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        Convert.ToInt32(element.Width / SCREEN_DPI * TARGET_DPI),
        Convert.ToInt32(element.Height / SCREEN_DPI * TARGET_DPI),
        TARGET_DPI, TARGET_DPI, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    // Render the visual to the bitmap.
    rtb.Render(element);

    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapEncoder encoder;
    encoder = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

    var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    encoder.Save(ms);
    ms.Flush();
    ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
}
```